# How to solve system.unauthorizedaccessexception access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, web, web-applications, base64

I am creating a file from base64 string and while creating file i am getting system.unauthorizedaccessexception if base64 string is image type and it was working fine in remaining file types

File.WriteAllBytes(imagepath, Convert.FromBase64String(yourBase64String));

can any one help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The executable doesn't have access to that file. Run the exe as administrator, or make sure you give it a location that it has access to.

Comment: Thanks for response i will try your suggestion